# How to pass information between similar components in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a component AllRow. Inside of AllRow, I reuse the Row component two times. Inside the Row component there are poster of movies and when i click on them i can watch there trailers. I want that if I play a video from first Row the other video (if playing) from the second Row stop automatically. How can I achieve this?

This is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import Row from "../Components/Row.js";
function AllRows() {
 
  return (
    <div>
      <Row/>
      <Row/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AllRows;
```

The Row component is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../Styling/row.css";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";
import axios from "../Module/axios.js";

function Row() {

  const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [trailerUrl, setTrailerUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchURL);
      setMovies(request.data.results);

      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchURL]);

  const opts = {
    height: "390",
    width: "100%",
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
    },
  };

  const handleClick = (movie) => {
    if (trailerUrl) {
      setTrailerUrl("");
    } else {
      movieTrailer(movie?.name || movie?.title || "")
        .then((url) => {
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
          setTrailerUrl(urlParams.get("v"));
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  };
  return (
<div>
      <div>
{movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            src="poster image source source"
            key={movie.id}
            alt={movie.title}
            onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
          />
       ))}
      </div>

      {trailerUrl && (
        <YouTube className="row__video" videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

I'm fetching data from tmdb API. I have tried many things but couldn't find any solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the state of the playing video in the AllRow component.

```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Row from '../Components/Row.js';
function AllRows() {
  // To keep a track of the playing trailer amongst all the rows
  const [playingTrailer, setPlayingTrailer] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Row playingTrailer={playingTrailer} setPlayingTrailer={setPlayingTrailer} />
      <Row playingTrailer={playingTrailer} setPlayingTrailer={setPlayingTrailer} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
   function Row({playingTrailer, setPlayingTrailer}) {
      const base_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/';
      const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
      const [trailerUrl, setTrailerUrl] = useState('');
    
    
      // to keep track of the video
      const videoRef = null
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          const request = await axios.get(fetchURL);
          setMovies(request.data.results);
    
          return request;
        }
        fetchData();
      }, [fetchURL]);
    
    
      /**
       * If playingTrailer changes and the displayed trailer in this <Row> is different from playingTrailer stop the video player
       */
      useEffect(() => {
        if(trailerUrl !== playingTrailer && videoPlayerRef !== null){
            videoPlayerRef.pauseVideo()
        }
      },[playingTrailer])
    
      const opts = {
        height: '390',
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,
        },
      };
    
      const handleClick = (movie) => {
        if (trailerUrl) {
          setTrailerUrl('');
        } else {
          movieTrailer(movie?.name || movie?.title || '')
            .then((url) => {
              const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
              setTrailerUrl(urlParams.get('v'));
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
      };
      /**
       * use when the video playing, set the playing trailer in AllRows
       * @param {*} event 
       */
      const onPlay= (event) => {
        setPlayingTrailer(trailerUrl)
      }
      /**
       * When video is ready, keep a ref on the player (maybe there's a better option to keep the video ref...)
       * @param {*} event 
       */
      const onReady = (event) => {
        videoRef = event.target
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {movies.map((movie) => (
              <img
                src="poster image source source"
                key={movie.id}
                alt={movie.title}
                onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
    
          {trailerUrl && (
            <YouTube
              className="row__video"
              videoId={trailerUrl}
              opts={opts}
              onReady={onReady}
              onPlay={onPlay}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
```